# Programming a Packet Blocker (basic firewall) in C++ for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, networking, firewall

I am interested in programming a basic firewall that blocks packets according to user-defined rules.

Basically, I already programmed the part that deals with the rules and everything is okay, but now I'm supposed to implement the firewall itself (the hard part, I guess).

I searched a lot, and found a couple of links full of details e.g [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3405/Developing-Firewalls-for-Windows-XP) and [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366510%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The second (Windows Filtering Platform) seems most relevant, now, there doesn't seem to be any data about ACTUALLY getting started, the code snippets in the site (well, in this specific subject) don't explain the subject all too well.

I would like to know simply how to block a packet matching a certain rule, so that includes a couple of stages:

1. Listening for ANY incoming packets, all ports, IPs and protocols.
2. Checking if the packet matches the certain rules.
3. If it **does** match, let it through. If it **doesn't**, capture it and block it over there.

Now, stage 2 is actually already programmed, I just need to match it according to stage 1 (what class/structure is used to represent the packet). I'm not sure about doing stage 1, and stage 3.

First, how do I even listen to ALL of the connections in the computer?

Second, how do I manage the packet I captured, letting it through OR blocking it.

Help would be much appreciated. I mean raw WinAPI, but if there's a certain good API that works on windows (8, in specific) I'd be happy to test it.

Comment: It's unclear whether this question should be closed as 'too broad', 'unclear what you're asking', 'off-topic because it doesn't include any code', or 'off-topic because it is a request for off-site resources or recommendations'.

Comment: Punch "windows packet filter" into your favorite search engine.

Comment: libpcap and tcpdump? Could you not achieve your packet capture and analysis with such?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're right - you've left the hard part to last :-)

You need to write a network driver to position itself in the network stack to intercept packets from the network card and then filter them. There are ways to get round this (eg using the [packet injection functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff569975%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)) but they;re almost as hard as writing your own driver.

There are open source drivers you could look at - [winpcap](http://www.winpcap.org/devel.htm) is the one most people are familiar with as it is the packet capture driver used by Wireshark.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't understand much from the description (of Winpcap), does it have the ability to drop a packet ?

Comment: @Joseph no, its just a packet sniffer, but it might give you a start.

Comment: I actually did program my own packet sniffer, that won't help me, though, because I can't drop a packet according to my Packet Blocker's rules. All I need is the ability to capture a packet, view its information and have the ability to drop it or let it through.